# Is there a way of registering all interfaces in Autofac for a component using JSON configuration similar to .AsImplementedInterfaces()

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, .net-5, autofac-configuration

Is it possible to have some components registered through JSON in the same way one would register a component with .AsImplementedInterfaces()? Or are modules the only way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is not a way via configuration to do `AsImplementedInterfaces` equivalent. Module is probably the right way to go in this case. Configuration is really more for "I have one or two things I need to swap and it won't be a problem to outline exactly what those things are." It's definitely not intended to replace or be feature-comparable with code-based registration.

Comment: Thank you! Modules do seem to make more sense here.